# Using Excel formulas compare 2 columns and match if there is a substring

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Struggling to do this in Python so trying Excel formula.

these are the logic steps I would like to do:

1. Convert both columns to lowercase
2. if keyword matches any cell/s in the data string data string then identify the keyword and data string match and and put in another cell.
3. If there are no matches for the keyword then can put not found

How can I do this?

input example below: (as you can see data strings can be in any order)

[image]
output example:

output example:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: thank you - this gives me all 'not founds' I want to check one keyword and scan the whole list of data strings - currently it ony looks at the cell next to it. how can I scan the full column?

Comment: Unclear why the first `apple` matches with `apple ipads` while the second `apple` matches with `apple is my fave`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your revisions...

You will need to type the correct value for d2. Then in d3 and going down, you can use this formula.

`=IF(OR(SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(D2,$B$2:$B$7)))=COUNTIFS($D$1:D2,D2),SUM(--ISNUMBER(FIND(D2,$B$2:$B$7)))=0),INDEX($A$2:$A$7,MATCH(D2,$A$2:$A$7,0)+1),D2)`

Then in e2 and going down, you can use this formula

`=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$7,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(LOWER(D2),LOWER($B$2:$B$7))),ISNUMBER(FIND(LOWER(D2),LOWER($B$2:$B$7)))*ROW($B$2:$B$7)-1),COUNTIFS($D$1:D1,D2)+1)),"not found")`

Remember to enter both of the formulas with control + shift + enter

[image]

Comment: wow thank you!! so currently I have one match name (e.g apple) and then can be 3 or more strings matching apple. Is it possible to get these as well as currently only the first one is being extracted?

Comment: If you look at my example, for grapes it returns The grapes are good for the first one, then Another Grape, then grape something. So it returns all three strings. I'm not sure what you mean - please post another screenshot in your example if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: What I meant is that the match list will only have the word once (I will update my input photo)  to be clear

Comment: thank you so much!! for some reason I am getting the same output in both column D and E - any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Updated again :)